# Add class to div when another empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a list with 3 divs. There are avatar, value, and data.

```js
if ($('.avatar').length === 0) {
  $('.date').css({
    'color': '#c7c7c7'
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list">

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img>
      </div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"></div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img>
      </div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Some "li .avatar" in my list are empty. I want to change the color of date when avatar empty.

I'm trying do it with it:

```
if ($('.avatar').length === 0) {
   $('.date').css({'color' : '#c7c7c7'});
};
```

It's working, but this change color of all div with class 'date'. How do I change the code so that the style is added only to that class date that is inside 'li' with an empty 'avatar'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with pure CSS:

```
.avatar:empty ~ .date {
   color: #c7c7c7;
}
```

```css
.avatar:empty~.date {
  color: #c7c7c7;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list">

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img>
      </div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"></div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img>
      </div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`:empty` selector](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) to target the empty `.avatar` element then use `.siblings(selector)` to get the target element the `.date`

```
$('.list li .avatar:empty').siblings('.date').css({'color' : '#c7c7c7'});
```

```js
$('.list li .avatar:empty').siblings('.date').css({'color' : '#c7c7c7'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list">

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img>
      </div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"></div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img>
      </div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your list and check the length of your `.avatar` children via the `.each()` function :

```js
$('.list li').each(function(){
  if($('.avatar',this).children().length == 0){
    $('.date',this).css({'color' : '#c7c7c7'});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<ul class="list">

 <li>
  <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img></div>
  <div class="value">000</div>
  <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="value">000</div>
  <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img></div>
  <div class="value">000</div>
  <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's working, but this change color of all div with class 'date'

You can `each` and `siblings`

```
$('.avatar').each( function(){
    if ( $( this ).html().trim().length === 0 ) 
    {
       $(this).siblings( ".date" ).css({'color' : '#c7c7c7'});
    };    
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.avatar').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html().trim().length === 0) {
    $(this).siblings( ".date" ).css({
      'color': '#c7c7c7'
    });
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list">

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"><img></div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"></div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="avatar"><img></div>
      <div class="value">000</div>
      <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the necessary subset using the `filter` `function` of jquery and perform the `css` change on the result:

```
$("li.avatar").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).text();
}).each(function() {$(this).siblings(".date").css({'color' : '#c7c7c7'});})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap the date div inside and write the java script as per below.

```
<li>
  <div class="avatar"><img src=...></img>
     <div class="date">0 semptember</div>
  </div>
  <div class="value">000</div>

</li>

var $div = $(this);
$div.find('.date').css({'color' : '#c7c7c7'});
```

Thanks,